# How to make react-native Picker stay at newly selected option?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a picker that I'm testing on iOS right now with two options. Every time I drag down from the first option to the second option, the picker immediately returns to the first option.

This is what my the code for my picker looks like.

```
<Picker 
      style={{
        width: 100,
      }}
      selectedValue={(this.state && this.state.pickerValue) || 'a'}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        this.setState({value});
      }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>
      <Picker.Item label={'Hello'} value={'a'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'World'} value={'b'} />
</Picker>
```

I want the selector to stay at the newly scrolled-to option. I've also removed the `|| 'a'` part of the `selectedValue` attribute but that didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: change onValueChange to this.setState({pickerValue: value});

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On value change you need to specify which property of the state changed and change it accordingly with **this.setState**

```
onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({pickerValue: value});
```

Complete Code

```
<Picker 
      style={{
        width: 100,
      }}
      selectedValue={(this.state && this.state.pickerValue) || 'a'}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        this.setState({pickerValue: value});
      }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>
      <Picker.Item label={'Hello'} value={'a'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'World'} value={'b'} />
</Picker>
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a functional component? One that does not have a `State` ?

Comment: Here I have a state value and another one value passing as a props from a component (i.e) If the user directly comes to the screen it needs to show the default and it should allow the user to pick another values. In the same way if the user passes a value from one screen to the picker, it needs to show the changed value and also needs to allow the user to pick the other values in the picker too

Comment: @KaranAsthana Functional components do use state through the `useState` API. The term you're looking for is probably a stateless component.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this and was facing the same issue, the scrolling reaches the new item and resets to the first item.
I have done this using stateless component (Hooks):

I have an **array of objects** as the *value* and **option** as *key*

```
const data = useState({
"options":[{
"name":"Dish 1","price":0},{"name":"Dish 2","price":0}]})
```

`const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)`

The Picker component:

```
<PickerIOS
    selectedValue={selected_choice}
    onValueChange={(value, index) => {
            set_selected_choice(index)
          }}
        >
          {data?.map((item, index) => (
            <PickerIOS.Item
              key={item}
              value={index}
              label={item.name}
            />
          ))}
</PickerIOS>
```

Here, I have stored the index of the array elements in the selected state and have updated it from the PickerIOS Item, keeping the **value** as **index**.

Answer (score -6):

I used this "hack":

```
render() {
    const values = ['1', '2'];

    return (
      <Picker
        value={this.state.value}
        onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
      >
      {
                <Picker
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
                >
                {
                    [<Picker.Item
                        label="n/a"
                        value={null}
                    />].concat(values.map(value => {
                            return (
                                <Picker.Item
                                    label={value}
                                    value={value}
                                />
                            )
                            })
                    ) 
                }
                </Picker>
    );
  }
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked a **year** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: Is this the recommended indenting? I'm new to React-Native, just asking.